# java.lang.ClassCastException one class to other

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am using the following code to execute while hit the submit button, I am getting the following error and not sure where the mistake was, can anyone gimme a suggest here?

```
private ModelAndView save(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {

        List<FundsProductPurpose> fppList = funderRepository.getFundsList();
        FundsProductPurpose fpp = fppList.get(0);

        return doMapping("result", "Funder details added successfully",
                request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return doMapping("result", "Unable to add funder details", request);
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mmf.model.FundsDetails cannot be cast to com.mmf.model.FundsProductPurpose
    at com.mmf.controllers.SaveFundsController.save(com.mmf.controllers.SaveFundsController:98)
```

Comment: You're trying to cast a `FundsDetails` into `FundsProductPurpose`. we don't really know these classes, so it's hard to say, but chances are you want `FundsDetails`to be a child-class of `FundsProductPurpose`.

Comment: line 98 is... FundsProductPurpose fpp = fppList.get(0);

Comment: Check your compiler warnings. It will warn you about “unsafe” aka “unchecked” operations and/or “raw type” usage…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From posted code, you created `FundsDetails` at `funderRepository`, but you got `FudsDetails` from `fundRepository`. You should create `FundsDetails` with `fundRepository`

```
 FundsDetails fundsDetails = new FundsDetails();
 fundsDetails.setIdStaticFunder(funderId);
   .....
 fundRepository.createFund(fundsDetails);// Use fundRepository
```

Comment: changed my code as you sugested... but still the same issue exists... I updated my question with new code

Comment: I am able to get the list from funderRepository.getFundsList();, but error happens only on line no 98..(FundsProductPurpose fpp = fppList.get(0);)